# Ajax response change location

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function in jquery that submit a form that is working fine, but i need different types of reaction according to the response, sometimes i need to show a message, sometimes reload the window, and other relocate the window

I have a problem with this last part, i dont know how can i detect that is a url, and change the location.

this is my script jquery

```
function process_form(type_form, id_content_error){

    var url = "url.php?form="+tipo_form;
    var response= document.getElementById(id_content_error);


        response.style.display='block';

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: url,
               data: $('#'+type_form).serialize(),
               success: function(data)
                {
                    if (data==1){
                        window.location.reload();
                    }else{
                        response.innerHTML=data; 
                    }
                }
        });


        return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
```

};

My php returns 3 types of sentences,

"1": when i need to reload the window.

"messaje": when i need to show something.

"some_url.php":when i need to relocate the window.

sorry for my english, and thanks

Comment: You suffixed the first 2 cases with indications of what they are.  Why didn't you do the same for the URL?

Comment: My response is dynamic, I need what brings me data to know where to relocate

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it adding this in the sucsess function

```
}else if (data.search(/.php/)!=-1){
    window.location = data;
}
```